# Unexpected result of `train_function` (Empty logs). Please use `Model.compile(..., run_eagerly=True)`, or `tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)`

Tags: python, keras, tf.keras, transformer-model

while implementing the transformer for internet traffic forecasting i am getting this error "ValueError: Unexpected result of `train_function` (Empty logs). Please use `Model.compile(..., run_eagerly=True)`, or `tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)` for more information of where went wrong, or file a issue/bug to `tf.keras`."

[The notebook link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1NEHpa_o6OsNBlG2a5IzfjympPc5mUXyU?usp=sharing)

Parameter values

```
{
    "look_back" : 7,
    "n_features" : 1,
    "horizon" : 7,

    "n_layers_init" : 2,
    "n_layers_end" : 6,

    "n_units_init" : 8,
    "n_units_end" : 512,

    "unit" : "lstm",

    "log_dir" : "log",
    "checkpoint_dir" : "checkpoint"

}
```

what to run this code